# Как проверить "реализуемость" Интента, не запуская его?

Tags: android, android-intent

Есть 2 приложения. Из одного приложения есть намерение открыть Окно другого приложения. Как составить следующее выражение:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("пакет",
            "пакет.нужное_окно"));

    if (intent != null)
    {
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "УСТАНОВИТЕ ВНАЧАЛЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ такое-то",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "пакет"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

То есть, НЕ ПЫТАТЬСЯ вначале запустить Намерение, а потом, словив ошибку, выполнить другое действие, а как ЗАРАНЕЕ узнать, что нужного Окна целевого приложения не существует?

"intent != null" было взято с англоязычного побратима этого сайта, но оно не работает.

Comment: обновил ответ - нашел то что вам необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить наличие активности можно так :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("пакет",
        "пакет.нужное_окно"));

if (getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).size() > 0)
{
    // Activity существует можно запускать
}
```

Comment: Проверил по-разному. Работает именно так, как надо. Благодарю. Желаю успехов в делах

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас используется неявный `intent`:

```
// Create the text message with a string
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

// Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

> Внимание! Возможна ситуация, когда на устройстве пользователя не будетникакого приложения, которое может откликнуться на неявный объект Intent, отправленный вами методу startActivity(). В этом случае вызов закончится неудачей, а работа приложения аварийно завершится. Чтобы проверить, будет получен ли операцией объект Intent, вызовите метод resolveActivity() для своего объекта Intent. Если результатом будет значение, отличное от null, значит, имеется хотя бы одно приложение, которое способно откликнуться на объект Intent и можно вызывать startActivity(). Если же результатом будет значение null, объект Intent не следует использовать и по возможности следует отключить функцию, которая выдает этот объект Intent.

взято из офф доков: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html?hl=ru

Если хотите использовать явный `intent`, тогда вам необходимо в `Manifest` проверяемой активности добавить `intent-filter`:

```
<activity
android:name=".YouCheckedActivity" >  
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

В коде объявить:

```
static final String CHECKED_ACTION = "com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION";
```

который присваиваете проверяемому `intent`:

```
Intent checkedIntent= new Intent();
checkedIntent.setAction(CHECKED_ACTION);
```

или можно сразу хардкодить (не рекомендуется):

```
checkedIntent.setAction("com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION");
```

---

**UPD**
проверка аналогична неявному `intent`:

```
// Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
if (checkedIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(checkedIntent);
}
```

---

**UPD 2**
Можно `intent` создавать напрямую (необходимая для запуска `Activity` во втором приложении в `Manifest` указано как `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`):

```
Intent checkedIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.foo.bar.YouApplication");
```

И далее аналогичная в первых двух случаях проверка

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, при явном Намерении что писать в условии if()? boolean A = checkedIntent; и проверяем А? при этом значение true - это когда Окно есть?

Comment: @St-st условие остается как и при неявном: 
    `if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}`
добавил в ответ в конце

Comment: К сожалению, после экспериментов мои опасения подтвердились. Суть опасений, что, все же, намерение НЕ ЯВНОЕ. Да, таким образом можно проверить, есть ли Окно в приложении, которое в манифесте имеет строку "com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION". Однако, Окно любого другого приложения может иметь эту же строку, пусть даже адреса/имена пакетов не совпадают. То есть это Намерение ищет НЕ ОКНО (Активити), а строку в манифесте. Поэтому задача не решена: как убедиться, что существует нужное Окно в каком-то определенном приложении.

Comment: `Если вы определяете собственные действия, обязательно используйте в качестве их префикса имя пакета вашего приложения.` из офф доков - кому может понадобиться подбирать Намерение вплоть до имен пакета - неясно.

Comment: я считаю, что это может сделать любой злоумышленник, а моя задача, как раз наоборот, - предотвратить это.

Comment: А учитывая легкость взлома, это может сделать даже самый начинающий разработчик. Я хочу использовать другое приложение в качестве ключа к первому (платное - ключ, бесплатное - основное). Подбирать злоумышленнику ничего не надо будет, достаточно открыть бесплатное приложение и посмотреть строку com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION, вставить его в свое приложение и вуаля, посторонний ключ готов.

Comment: @St-st т.е. вы хотите в активность другого приложения отправить некие секретные данные минуя проверку подлинности пользователя?

Comment: можно и так, а можно и ничего не отправлять, а просто проверить, установлено ли платное приложение (это в самом простом случае). А что Вы вкладываете в понятие проверка подлинности пользователя?

Comment: @St-st это был абстрактный пример - в вашем случае это можно просто дополнить: пользователя уплатившего за платную версию...
Кстати вот немного советов по защите Android приложений: https://xakep.ru/2016/12/26/android-reverse-debug-security/

Comment: @St-st добавил еще один способ - но его также можно вскрыть. Хотя есть у меня идея одного метода который вам вероятно подойдет))) Только думаю это уже другой вопрос - по защите приложения. Вопрос из заголовка покрыт полностью.

Comment: Если не секрет, поделитесь идеей по защите приложения. Мой мейл есть в описании профиля.